# Automap objects from different language

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper-6

I'm trying to find a way to have a mapping configuration that can map between totally different names from a list.

Our database is in Dutch and scaffolding tooling (like scaffold-dbcontext) keeps the table names for the DTO's. Outside our db related layers we would prefer English nouns.

Say I have the following

```
Afdeling
  Id: int
  TypeKode: string
  Werkenemers: Persoon[]

Department
  Id: int
  TypeCode: string
  Employees: Person[]
```

Given I know the following word mapping

```
Afdeling    Department
Kode        Code
Werkenemers Employees
Persoon     Person
```

Is it then possible to configure AutoMapper to be able to map as such:

```
Department department = Mapper.Map<Afdeling, Department>(afdeling);
```

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. You want to automatically map _properties_ of those classes, and those properties have names in different languages?

Comment: Expanded on my example. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Here is code sample, but note it's just *sample*. It shows general approach but is not complete and contains some unnecessary things, so make sure you understand what's going on there.

First, custom mapper:

```
class DictionaryMapper : ISourceToDestinationNameMapper {
    public Dictionary<string, string> Map { get; set; }
    public MemberInfo GetMatchingMemberInfo(IGetTypeInfoMembers getTypeInfoMembers, TypeDetails typeInfo, Type destType, Type destMemberType, string nameToSearch) {
        if (Map == null || !Map.ContainsKey(nameToSearch))
            return null;
        // map properties using Map dictionary
        return typeInfo.DestinationMemberNames
            .Where(c => c.Member.Name == Map[nameToSearch])
            .Select(c => c.Member)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then

```
var langMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// note that it's better to use two dictionaries - one for type names
// and another for properties
langMappings.Add("Afdeling", "Department");            
langMappings.Add("TypeKode", "TypeCode");            
langMappings.Add("Werkenemers", "Employees");            
langMappings.Add("Persoon", "Person");
// create reverse map
foreach (var kv in langMappings.ToArray())
    langMappings.Add(kv.Value, kv.Key);

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    // this will allow mapping type with name from dictionary key above
    // to another type indicated with name indicated by value
    // so, Afdeling to Department
    cfg.AddConditionalObjectMapper().Where((s, d) => langMappings.ContainsKey(s.Name) && langMappings[s.Name] == d.Name);
    cfg.AddMemberConfiguration()
    // this is default automapper configuration,
    // see http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conventions.html
    .AddMember<NameSplitMember>()
    .AddName<PrePostfixName>(_ => _.AddStrings(p => p.Prefixes, "Get"))
    // and this one is our custom one
    .AddName<DictionaryMapper>(_ => _.Map = langMappings);
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var result = mapper.Map<Afdeling, Department>(new Afdeling
{
    Id = 1,
    TypeKode = "code",
    Werkenemers = new[] {
        new Persoon() {Id = 2}
    }
});
```